# how to write algorithm to insert multiple elements in queue

Tags: algorithm

How can we write an algorithm to add multiple elements say 5 elements {1,2,3,4,5} in an queue
I searched a lot but found algorithm to insert only one item but I don't know how to run a loop to insert multiple elements.
the algorithm to insert one item which I found is

> 1. Start
> 2. Check if the Queue is full or not if(rear=N-1) THEN print “Queue is Full” and exit else goto step 3
> 3. Increment the rear
>      ++rear;
> 4. Add the item at the ‘rear’ position Q[rear]= item;
> 5. Exit

Comment: You might want to read some introductory information about C programming if you unclear where to start.

Comment: Insert one element into a queue... five times, using a different element for each insertion

Comment: my question is how to define a loop in algorithm

Comment: Needs external research on basic programming.

Comment: Forget about the queue for the moment and learn how to write a loop that prints "hello, world!" (or whatever you like) 5 times.

Comment: Create a vector or array of elements that you want to add to queue and loop over that adding each element to the queue. After each insertion check if queue is full or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0 Start
1 Initialize index variable to 0
2 Check if the number of the elements inserted (iterations) is equal M (where M is the number of the elements to insert). If it is, go to the step 7.
3 Check if the Queue is full or not if(rear=N-1) THEN print “Queue is Full” and exit  
4 Increment the rear ++rear;
5 Add the item at the ‘rear’ position Q[rear]= items[i];
6 Increment index variable and go to the step 2
7 Exit
```

Alternatively, you could check if the queue has space to put M elements before the loop. Steps from 1 to 6 can be implemented using `for` loop (of course, any other loop should do the trick).

Comment: @Subhanker It is added - note the steps 1, 2 and 6.